# Given an object how can I get the name used to describe it?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object(`mainObj`) which in turn has objects (say `obj1`, `obj2`, `obj3`). What I am trying to achieve is when I check for a condition iterating through every obj in the `mainObj` and if it holds true, I want to add only the name of that `obj` in an array of String. Something like,

```
for(obj in mainObj){
 if(obj holds condition){
    add the descriptor of the obj (in string format) to an array (not the entire obj)
 }
```

Comment: Have you made use of `Object.values` and `Object.keys` that would result in array of `values` and `keys` and you can compare the value and push the respective key to your array. If you are using `lodash`, then make use of `each` method in that library

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate over your object keys, then use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the keys, here I am checking if the inner objects have a property `show` and if this property is truthy:

```js
const mainObj = {
  obj1: { show: true, a: 1 },
  obj2: { show: false, a: 2 },
  obj3: { a: 3 },
  obj4: { show: true, b: 1 }
};

const result = Object.keys(mainObj).filter(key => mainObj[key].show);

console.log(result);
```

If you want to use a [`for-in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, you have to make sure the property is part of the object and is not inherited from its protype chain using [`Object.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```js
const mainObj = {
  obj1: { show: true, a: 1 },
  obj2: { show: false, a: 2 },
  obj3: { a: 3 },
  obj4: { show: true, b: 1 }
};

const result = [];
for (const prop in mainObj) {
  if (mainObj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && mainObj[prop].show) {
    result.push(prop);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```